# How can I make my application wait for specific amount of time?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to add some Items to a listbox, but the thing is, I want the application waits for 500ms after adding each item then adds the next item; so I used the code below:

```
    reduction_list.Items.Add("ID");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

    reduction_list.Items.Add("Name");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

    reduction_list.Items.Add("City");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

    reduction_list.Items.Add("Major");
```

but the application waits for 1500ms and adds the whole 4 items all together.

Comment: Is this in a asp.net application or a winforms application?

Comment: sorry I didn't make correct tag. it's winforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you didn't update the interface after adding, so just add this after each call:

```
reduction_list.Invalidate();
reduction_list.Update();
```

The problem here is that you didn't give the interface time to update itself, since you are executing the code at UI thread. So adding [Invalidate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx) or [Refresh()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx) after each add will cause the application to refresh the `reduction_list` view.

Comment: Even if this works, it is never, ever recommended to make the UI freeze - it will prevent any other user interaction. In this case the UI is locked against interactions for 1.5 seconds which in my opinion is far to long.

Comment: @Anders yes I agree, that comes to my mind, but we don't know his requirements, maybe he wanted it to be that why, how knows..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are making the UI thread sleep, which means that it never gets a chance to redraw the UI with the new items.

You should use a timer instead. (The exact timer class to use depends on what UI framework you are using - Winforms or WPF. Please tag your question appropriately.)